# how to proxy s3 images through ec2

Tags: canvas, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Because IE10 and its predecessors do not support Image's crossOrigin, a client's canvas cannot show images from s3/cloudfront.

To solve this problem, I assume I will need to proxy the data via my main server, an ec2 instance.

I am wondering if it is better to use s3put to get the data to my ec2 instance, **or** better to just use http proxies to get it.

Also -- better to handle this in django/php/etc or better to handle it with apache (not sure how I would do that, but maybe you've a good idea to share).

Or maybe there is some better way altogether to handle this?  Mount my s3 bucket as a drive?

Comment: a simple `<?php echo file_get_contents($GET['s3_url']) ?>` would technically be enough. not a GOOD way to go, but would do the job.

Comment: The way I have done it in the past was by using a proxy in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inspired way to workaround the problem:

http://dira.ro/2011/10/17/heroku-s3-canvas-and-the-security-error-of-doom

(I have taken a similar approach, but just base64 encode my images before putting them onto s3.)

And here is another way to work around the problem, but requires flash:
http://easyxdm.net/wp/